# Multiple Project in 1 solution vs 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, migration

I have various individual projects in VS 2003 with some common files(Admin) in each of them. Now I want to migrate all these projects into VS 2008. I also want all the projects to be under 1 single solution so that I have 1 common admin section in the main project and each project as subproject

Ex
Main Project
       - Admin Section
                -Sub Proj1
               -Sub Proj2
                -SubProj3

Just want to know if this is a feasible thing to do. Right now I have separate web.configs for each project, how is this going to change if I combine the projects in 1 solution?
How does project compiling/building works in such situation?

Any advice will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's an emacs shortcut for what you want...

Answer (score 2):

You said your project was in VS 2003.  If you are using .NET 1.1 you will have a problem with VS 2008.  I believe 2008 only supports .NET 2.0-3.5.

Comment: yes..I have to convert the project to support .net 2.0-3.5 first And then combine all of them in 1 solution

Answer (score 1):

Config files "cascade" - your app will query up the chain, from the one closest to it all the way up to machine.config, until it finds one that contains the information it wants.  So there should not be an issue with your web-config files; they would each remain with their own project.

As far as feasability, yes, you can have multiple projects - even multiple web projects - in the same solution.  However, you cannot nest them as you described.  Each project must be a distinct child of the solution.

Comment: Thanks..so web.config is not a big issue

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2008 does not support subprojects.

If you have a common code (not files), you can share them by creating a project and reference it to any other project that requires the code.

If you have content (not compiled) files, you can add them into the project as resource files and access them programatically.

This does not work for web files (e.g.: .htm, .css, .js, etc.).

Comment: Visual Studio Express, maybe.  VS2008 pro, etc. definitely allow multiple projects, in any configuration you can envision.

Comment: Ahh... I misunderstood your comment.  Re-reading the OP, you are correct, the configuration he described won't work.

Comment: Right now I have a folder /Admin in each individual project. This folder has files which are shared in all these projects. So now what I want now is only 1 /Admin in the main project. Each individual project won't have this folder, they will refer to the /Admin in the main project. Did i make things clear?

Comment: So what you really want to do is to merge the projects.

Comment: @Mithil What files are inside that folder?

Comment: various files, most of them are aspx and ascx pages